# Templates for single page and others (elementor free) wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How can I override single page template using elemementor free ...
When I create single.php in my theme or write anything nothing happen ..

How can I achieve the template overriding please explain..

Answer (score 0):

Use page.php to override page templates